# Dual H264 videos inside single MPEG-TS stream with GStreamer: audio/video sync?

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264, video-encoding, mpeg2-ts

For a research prototype, I need to have two synchronized HD video streams and one audio stream inside a streamable container for real-time communication (basically Skype with an additional secondary video stream). The only container format I've found that works as intended is MPEG-TS. I have two working pipelines which I put together based on various examples, but there's a number of things I haven't fully understood yet. First of all, the pipelines:

Sender pipeline (with videotestsrc as a stand-in):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -ve mpegtsmux name=mux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=$1 port=5000 \
    v4l2src                   ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720                ! videoconvert ! queue leaky=downstream ! x264enc noise-reduction=10000 tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true threads=2 key-int-max=15 ! mux. \
    videotestsrc is-live=true ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=10/1 ! videoconvert ! queue leaky=downstream ! x264enc noise-reduction=10000 tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true threads=2 key-int-max=15 ! mux. \
    pulsesrc                  ! audio/x-raw,channels=1,rate=8000                 ! queue leaky=downstream ! opusenc bitrate=8000 ! mux.
```

Receiver pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -ve udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=MP2T ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsparse ! tsdemux name=mux \
    mux. ! h264parse ! queue leaky=downstream ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false \
    mux. ! h264parse ! queue leaky=downstream ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false \
    mux. ! queue leaky=downstream ! opusdec ! autoaudiosink sync=false
```

This setup generates about 500 kB/s of network traffic, which is pretty close to the expected value, and works just fine on localhost. I'm using the echo plugin for Pulseaudio for echo cancellation, so that's also covered.

Most of my previous issues (see below) have now been resolved by a) using MPEG2-TS inside RTP on the sender side, and `rtpjitterbuffer` on the receiver side, and b) by using `queue leaky=downstream` everywhere. As per Florian Zwoch's suggestion, I also removed intra-refresh from x264enc.

The only issue that's now left is that I have a constant, but unpredictable offset between audio and video. Occasionally, it's almost in sync and also stays that way, but on other occasions, it's off by 1-2 seconds, which is enough to be annoying. I assume I could somehow get rid of this by tweaking the queue parameters?

---

Original set of issues, preserved for archiving:

1. When actually using a real network between two separate machines (high-bandwidth WiFi with nearly 100% signal strength), the quality degrades massively. There doesn't seem to be any noticeable packet loss, and 500 kB/s isn't exactly taxing for this WiFi connection. What gives?
2. What exactly is the function of the queue elements on the receiver side? AFAICT if I set max-size... properties to 0, then they would just buffer indefinitely?
3. Even on a fairly powerful machine, the sender keeps issuing warnings - how can an 8 kBit/s audio encoder "fall behind"?

```
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstPulseSrc:pulsesrc0: Can't record audio fast enough
Additional debug info:
gstaudiobasesrc.c(849): gst_audio_base_src_create (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstPulseSrc:pulsesrc0:
Dropped 1600 samples. This is most likely because downstream can't keep up and is consuming samples too slowly.
```

Comment: What does `quality decrease` mean exactly? Do you understand the `x264enc` options you are setting? Is it really what you are after?

Comment: as for 2. Yes, but you are missing the `time` variant if your intention was to make them infinite. Another purpose of them is to add threads from getting data from the demuxer so you don't run into deadlocks.

Comment: Quality: was getting almost unrecognizeably blocky as soon as there was movement. I've seen a noticeable improvement by adding `rtpmp2t[de]mux` elements; I believe the issue was packet reordering which MPEG-TS can't resolve on its own.

Comment: x264enc options: I understand most of them, except intra-refresh, didn't really get that one (but it was recommended for streaming scenarios apparently).

Comment: LBNL, queue: I've switched to `queue leaky=downstream` on the receiver side, and can now reliably stop and restart both sender and receiver. Still wondering whether I should add those on the sender side, too?

Comment: Do not use intra-refresh if you don't exactly understand how it works codec wise and understand its implications on random access and streaming scenarios (there may be reasons depending on your use case, but mostly - no). With blocking you need to be more specific whether it's block-ness due to encoder bit-rate buffer being exhausted or if its due to packet loss/packet reordering. These are completely different things.

Comment: I've solved most of my previous issues by tweaking the queue parameters, and by using RTP + jitterbuffer to wrap the MPEG2-TS. The only thing that's left is a unpredictable, but constant (for each run) offset between audio and video. Any further suggestions would be much appreciated :-)